# I pissed in the pool GIT style - ftp'd files into repo now GIT not in sync

Tags: git, github

#### Ok so here's the scenario:

- Host the code on github - push to `origin`
- For deployment - push to `deploy` *(bare repo on bluehost that has a hook to push to www folder for all to see site)*

So, workflow would be like this since I work at two different locations:

- pull latest from github *(changes made at different location and pushed the night before)*
- work locally and commit changes
- push to `origin` *(github)*
- after everything is good need this thing online, so master is pushed to `deploy` *(bluehost)*

Still with me?

This has worked for some time and for me it's *awesome*

**Then I pissed in the pool**

I accidentally ftp'd files to bluehost *(sublime sftp was enabled)*, now when I try to push `deploy` the latest and greatest to bluehost I get the error that **everything is up to date** and if I make some changes, do a new `commit` then push, I get the error **such and such file will be overwritten with merge, commit or stash ...**

The **local repo and the git repo are all in check**, it's the bluehost one that is messed up.

**Please help me fix this.**  I have tried googling this and reading other posts here but everything seems to not solve my problem.  I tried `push --force` but to no avail.

Any ideas would be great. Or should I just erase the whole bluehost folder and start over with a brand new git repo to get things copacetic again?

**EDIT:**
out put from git

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\www\testingboard>git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean

C:\xampp\htdocs\www\testingboard>git push deploy master
danferth@danferth.com's password:
Everything up-to-date
```

#### Make an edit to single file (index.php

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\www\testingboard>git add -A

C:\xampp\htdocs\www\testingboard>git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   index.php
#
```

#### Commit change to index.php

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\www\testingboard>git commit -m "added mobile variable to index.p
hp"
[master e0be437] added mobile bariable to index.php
1 file changed, 5 insertions(+)
```

#### push to github (works)

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\www\testingboard>git push origin master
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 353 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/danferth/breadBoard.git
9e9f3c1..e0be437  master -> master
```

#### push to deploy (notice the other files that were ftp'd are there as well)

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\www\testingboard>git push deploy master
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 353 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: From /home4/danferth/git/breadboard
remote:    9e9f3c1..e0be437  master     -> origin/master
remote: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by
merge:
remote:         .sass-cache/6329d896b0dd00f287815f75641600307d9f0023/css_didI.sc
ssc
remote:         _START/pageTitle.php
remote:         assets/custom_css/css_didI.css
remote:         assets/custom_css/css_didI.scss
remote:         content/p_didI.php
remote:         didI.php
remote:         index.php
remote:         template.php
remote: Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
remote: Aborting
remote: Updating 0dc9e3d..e0be437
To danferth@danferth.com:~/git/breadboard.git
9e9f3c1..e0be437  master -> master

C:\xampp\htdocs\www\testingboard>
```

Comment: please provide the actual output of `git status` and `git push deploy`  oh, and +1 for the title from me too :-)

Comment: A more descriptive title might help other users with a similar problem to find this question in the future. :)

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek see my edit for output. If i make a new commit say to `index.php` then push it will git the error that it will be overwritten with merge then aborts.  Any suggestions

Comment: Are you on the master branch locally?

Comment: @nzifnab yes, on master locally, should I be working on a `working` branch localy and push to `master` on github?

Comment: @TimothyShields I hear you will work on a different Title once problem solved thanks for the input :)

Comment: Do you have shell access to the deploy server?

Comment: @Arjan yes I do, that's how I installed GIT client onto bluehosts servers. then created bare repo that pushes to www folder.  I have a different one for each subdomain.

Comment: @WesleyMurch title fixed

Comment: and if you make a change, commit it, and then push, what's the output?

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek made a change to single file (index.php) then pushed to github with no problems.  When pushing to deploy you can see in the code above that index.php and the other files ftp'd cause a problem.  Any ideas?

Comment: `git push -f origin deploy master` should work, but Arjan's answer should work if that does not.

Comment: I would think the correct way to do this would be to set `deploy` as a `mirror` of master, but I'm not at your installation.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek tried `git push -f origin deploy master` as you suggested. returned `error: src refspec deploy doese not match any.  error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github......git'` I used putty to go into the `www` folder and did a `git status` but it returned a slew of files, guessing the deploy is way out of date. tried to `git checkout` a single file and returned `file does not match any known to git` Any ideas thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: @hd1 not familiar with this method, will look it up and possibly go with it once i can get everything working again as I'm not apposed to pushing to deploy from a single location.  thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the deploy server, use shell access and go to the www folder (the git repo checkout). Then use `git status` to get a list of files that are not in sync. Then use `git checkout -- <paths>` to restore those files from the git repo, so they're back in sync. Then you should be able to `git pull` on the server, or just `git push deploy` your local changes.

Since you're using a post-commit hook, the changes are already present in the bare repo on the deploy server but just not yet in the checked out www location. So a `git pull` there should get your webserver up to date.

Comment: I used putty to go into the `www` folder and did a `git status`, it returned a slew of files, guessing the deploy is way out of date with all my messing around trying to fix things. So tried to `git checkout` a single file as you suggested and returned `file does not match any known to git` Any ideas thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: in the www folder, do `git checkout -- .` - Don't mess around with individual files, and don't leave out the `--` part.

Comment: @danferth: As already mentioned, use `git checkout -- .` if there are lots of unmatched files.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek worked! thank you guys for all your help on this